# Performance - Query on Database and Query on Datatable

Tags: c#, database, performance, datatable

I have selected number of data that is filtered.

Based on the results
I have to make several more iterations of query.

Now I can go with 2 options:

1). Querying on the DataBase by improving the filtered query everytime

OR

2). Taking the filtered data to DataTable first time - when queried and then perform more filtering on that DataTable -(no need to query on the DataBase).

In which situation the performance is more?

P.S.: I know the same kind of question was asked before. But didn't get the proper answer. :)

Comment: My gut feelings says that the DataTable based approach would be faster because you are querying a in memory data structure. But you can always measure both scenarios and find out

Comment: Funnily enough, one of the first things I'd do in this scenario would be "remove `DataTable`"...

Comment: Frankly, it also makes a huge difference here whether you are talking about "5 thousand rows" vs "10 million rows"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **already have** a wider set of data in memory, then "2" will almost universally be faster; no network hop, no bandwidth, no server-side time. Just an in-memory filter. Even in a stateless environment such as ASP.NET it would be common to cache the results of a query (parameterised) like that, so that you can re-use the results between pages.

Don't take "2" to absurd levels, of course... starting with the entire table, or a significant number of rows, is bad on many levels:

- large initial cost
- makes no/little use of indexing
- lots to process in memory

**However**, in many common scenarios, you would typically query just the *first page* of results  and the *count*, so you don't actually have that set of data (you can't deduce, from 1 page and a count, what a filtered subset looks like). So "1" becomes the better option (but retaining caching of the paged results too).

Answer (score 1):

Proper answer: you need to decide what is expected/desired performances, than **measure** approaches your are interested in and see which one fits.

Please note that you need to measure prottypes on data sets that are close approximation of real data. Since 2 approaches you've suggested are explicit tradeoff between memory usage and IO/network access it is not possible to predict results without trying on your real data on machines that are reasonably close to your production system in performance.